# How to use enum types with Scanner

Tags: java, enums, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

thank you so much for your help in adv.!

I get an error when using scanner with enum type. However I was not allowed to use Buffer (InputStreamReader) in this task. What is the best work around it?

I receive following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

at ui.Application.runCLI(Application.java:33)
at ui.Application.main(Application.java:13)
```

The code:

```
package ui;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

```
static String command;

public enum Command {
    CONNECT, DISCONNECT, SEND, LOGLEVEL, HELP, QUIT, EXIT
}

private static void run(Scanner sc) {
    // String command; // ready for the input

    boolean done = false; // ready for the menu loop
    while (!done) { // keep on until done

        System.out
                .println("Milestone1: Connection and interation with TCP server");
        System.out
                .println("-------------------Please select on of the commandso-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("connect");
        System.out.println("disconnect");
        System.out.println("send");
        System.out.println("logLevel");
        System.out.println("help");
        System.out.println("quit");
        System.out.println("exit");

        command = sc.nextLine(); // take user input         
        Command cmd=null;
        try{
        cmd=Command.valueOf(command.toUpperCase());
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            return;
        }
        switch (cmd) {

        case EXIT: // exit menu
            done = true;// condition for breaking the loop
            break;

        case CONNECT:

            System.out.print(" IP adress: ");

            try {
                String userInput = sc.toString(); // user Input

                System.out.println(" Port: ");

                int userInput1 = sc.nextInt();// user Input

                if (userInput1 >= 0) {

                    System.out.println(" EcoClient>" + " " + command + " "
                            + userInput + " " + userInput1);
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("Entered value for Port is negative number or IP adress length < 7 || > 15, not in n.n.n.n format ");
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e) {// throw exception in case of illogical
                                    // input
                System.out.println("\nBad input, please try again ");
                sc.nextLine(); // remove leftover "\n"
            }

            break;

        case DISCONNECT:

            System.out.println(" EcoClient>" + " " + command);

            break;

        case SEND:

            System.out
                    .println("Please enter " + " Hello World " + "phrase");
            try {
                String userInput = sc.toString(); // user Input
                System.out.println(" EcoClient>" + " " + command + " "
                        + userInput);

            }

            catch (Exception e) {// throw exception in case of illogical
                                    // input

                System.out.println("\nBad input, please try again ");
                sc.nextLine(); // remove leftover "\n"
            }
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL:
            try {
                System.out.println(" EcoClient>" + " " + command + "< "
                        + "current log status" + " >");
            }

            catch (Exception e) {// throw exception in case of illogical
                                    // input

                System.out.println("\nBad input, please try again ");
                sc.nextLine(); // remove leftover "\n"

            }
            break;

        case HELP:
            try {
                System.out
                        .println("Following set of commands provide following functionalities:"
                                + " connect: establishes connection to the eco server "
                                + "disconnect: disconnects from the server and receives confirmation message "
                                + "send: sends the message to the server "
                                + "logLevel: prints out current log status"
                                + "quit: quits and notifies user about program shut down "
                                + "exit: cancel the input");

            }

            catch (Exception e) {// throw exception in case of illogical
                                    // input

                System.out.println("\nBad input, please try again ");
                sc.nextLine(); // remove leftover "\n"
            }
            break;

        case QUIT:

            try {
                System.out.println(" EcoClient> " + command);

            }

            catch (Exception e) {// throw exception in case of illogical
                                    // input

                System.out.println("\nBad input, please try again ");
                sc.nextLine(); // remove leftover "\n"

            }
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Does not recognise "
                    + "the input, pl. try again");

        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);// will take user input

    run(sc);

}
```

}

Comment: Don't forget to put the word `static` in the declaration of `main` - and also, either instantiate the class before calling `run` or declare `run` as static too.

Comment: Thank you however adding static does not solve the problem

Comment: The stacktrace mentions `runCLI` instead of the `run` above?

Comment: Sure, but it solves a different problem.  You really do need it.  But I don't think the error message you've quoted matches the source code you've shown.  Are you sure this is the actual version that's giving you that error?

Answer (score 2):

`sc.nextLine()` returns a String.  You will need to convert it into an instance of `Command` (on which you are using `switch`) using the static method `Command.valueOf(String)` which parses a string and returns the matching `Command` instance.

Here's the basics:

```
command = sc.nextLine(); // take user input
Command cmd = null;
try {
    cmd = Command.valueOf(command.toUpperCase());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, sorry."); //This is given on invalid input.  Put whatever type of error message you want here.
    return;
}
switch (cmd) {
//...
```

Comment: Thank you Jim Garrison, however the same error persists

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

 at ui.Application.runCLI(Application.java:33)
 at ui.Application.main(Application.java:13)

Comment: I copied my code from eclipse into netbeans and its working there now. Which is strange, as I keep on receiving error in eclipse. Moreover it seems that I leave loop prematurely when I choose "send" or "connect": "IP" address or "port Number"